# HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure in .NET Core Web Application

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc

I cloned a .NET core web application project from a git repository I haven't worked on in awhile onto a new computer. Although I'm not getting any errors in Visual Studio 2017, when I try to run the program locally I get the error page cited below in the browser.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to where to look for problems or settings I should change?

[HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIbbG.png)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot

Comment: I don't see the place in your question where it says you tried the link on the error dialog in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I needed to modify my visual studio install to include .NET Core 1.0-1.1 development tools for web.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the DLL name must not contain a space. For example the dll name is "my own web api.dll" and then you will get the above error message as well.

- Check if your target server has got correct version of core hosting bundles installed and correct values in web.config.
  https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/400/how-to-fix-iis-http-error-502-5-in-asp-net-core
- Check if your dll file name contains space in it. If yes, remove all spaces in it via assembly name in your project property of visual studio.